# Does hyphenation create a prefix?

Tags: hyphenation

When two words are hyphenated do they always become one word?  Or does it depend on why you use the hyphen?

For example 'four-wheeled carts'.  Has 'four' become a prefix or is the purpose of the hyphen to simply imply the relationship between the two words?

Cheers

Comment: The hyphen in four-wheeled attach the two together so that each cart is understood to have four wheels, rather than the possibility that there are four carts that are wheeled.

Comment: I hope we will simply see _four_ as modifying _wheeled_ and not call it a prefix, otherwise we will get an avalanche of questions like "how can _noun_ be used as a prefix when the dictionary doesn't mention that use?", much like we now get that same question about _noun_ being used as an adjective because of attributive use.

Comment: Some linguists regard open compounds such as 'ink well' as single words. And everybody would describe 'ink well' as a compound noun (when it is being used as one).

Comment: oerkelens I hoped so but sadly I've now found examples of a compound adjective (e.g. 6-page document) which leads one to think of the number as a prefix of the compound adjective.  The problem I have is that if there was no risk of confusion with readability  then you wouldn't need the hyphen and then you'd have two words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Hyphenating two adjectives creates a compound adjective, composed of two distinct words, connected by a hyphen for clarity.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier):

> A compound modifier (also called a compound adjective, phrasal adjective, or adjectival phrase) is a compound of two or more attributive words: That is, more than one word that together modify a noun.

Comment: Many thanks Davo.  It was what I wanted to hear but regardless I appreciate your time and the reference,  Cheers